# How do I get PHP and MySQL working on IIS 7.0?

Tags: php, mysql, iis-7

Okay, I've looked all over the internet for a good solution to get PHP and MySQL working on IIS7.0. It's nearly impossible, I've tried it so many times and given up in vain. Please please help by linking some great step-by-step tutorial to adding PHP and MySQL on IIS7.0 from scratch. PHP and MySQL are essential for installing any CMS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you taken a look at this:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis7/

MySQL should be pretty straight forward.

Let us know what problems you're encountering...

Answer (score 2):

I've been given a PHP / MySQL web site that I'm to host with IIS 7.0 on 64-bit Windows Server 2008.

I'm a .NET / MSSQL developer, and am unfamiliar with either PHP or MySQL.

> **[Kev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419/kev)** wrote:
>
> Have you taken a look at this…

I don't know if any one implementation of Win64 PHP is more authoratative or popular than another.

I'm going to try following the steps in Kev's [Enable FastCGI support in IIS7.0](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-70/) article with file *php-5.2.5-x64-2007-11-12.zip* from [fusion-x lan](http://www.fusionxlan.com/PHPx64.php).

It's "PHP Version 5.2.5 (x64)", but according to [php.net](http://www.php.net/downloads.php), the latest version is PHP 5.2.6.  Oh, well.

---

1. Make sure "ISAPI Extensions" are installed in IIS (mine were).
2. Download and then unzip *php-5.2.5-x64-2007-11-12.zip*
3. Copy contents of folder *php-5.2.5 (x64)* into *C:\php*
4. Copy file *C:\php\php.ini-dist* into folder *C:\Windows*
5. Rename file *C:\Windows\php.ini-dist* as *php.ini*
6. Edit *php.ini* in Notepad.  Remove leading semi-colon (;) from line:

   ```
   ;extension=php_mysql.dll
   ```
7. Save and close
8. Copy file *C:\php\ext\php_mysql.dll* into folder *C:\Windows\System32*
9. Within IIS Manager's "Handler Mappings", choose "Add Script Map…"

   ```
   Request path: *.php
   Executable:   C:\php\php5isapi.dll
   Name:         PHP
   ```
10. Install MySQL (someone had already installed [MySQL 5.0](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.0.html) for me).
11. Create file *C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.php* as

    ```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>PHP Information</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php phpInfo(); ?>
    </body>
    </html>
    ```
12. Navigate to *http://localhost/test.php* in your web browser.  You will see a page of information about PHP.

---

Roadblock: [How do I get PHP to work with ADOdb and MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155308/how-do-i-get-php-to-work-with-adodb-and-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to work via FastCGI. But I haven't had great success (using Vista). I can get PHP to run, but it crashes after a page loads (FastCGI does). So I'm modding you up. I'd like to see a reliable answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with windows/apache it's just a matter of install MySQL, I can't Imagine that IIS/Apache has anything to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

Apache is a major pain to get running in Vista. And II7 (and 6) are suppose to run PHP fine. So why bother with Apache?

Comment: i had no trouble with apache itself, only the php's session and upload dirs had to be set specially

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest if you are going for a PHP and MySQL install to instead use [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). It works great and is easy to add extensions and modify everything. I use it for work and love it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the IIS developers has an excellent walkthrough here:

http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2006/10/31/PHP-on-IIS.aspx

However, for the love of god why?

Comment: We are a dot net shop, but one of our customers dumped a home brew of php4 mysql4 phpmyadmin and their own code. It would take 3 months of rewrite or just run it on a stand alone machine to rot in cyberspace. The reason is you use what you know, and what you can get away with.