# How do I get PHP to work with ADOdb and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, windows, iis, adodb

I'm trying to get a PHP site working in IIS on Windows Server with MySQL.

I'm getting this error…

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\inetpub...\adodb\drivers\adodb-mysql.inc.php on line 363

---

Update…

This link outlines the steps I followed to install PHP on my server:
[How do I get PHP and MySQL working on IIS 7.0 ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919/how-do-i-get-php-and-mysql-working-on-iis-70#94341)
(note especially steps 6 and 8 regarting php.ini and php_mysql.dll).

Only two lines in the phpinfo report reference SQL:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

> Configure Command:
> cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-mysqlnd"
>
> sql.safe_mode:
> Local Value Off, Master Value Off

[PHP Configure Command http://img79.imageshack.us/img79/2373/configurecommandmw8.gif](http://img79.imageshack.us/img79/2373/configurecommandmw8.gif)

[PHP sql.safe_mode http://img49.imageshack.us/img49/3066/sqlsafemoderu6.gif](http://img49.imageshack.us/img49/3066/sqlsafemoderu6.gif)

---

Update…

I found the solution: [How do I install MySQL modules within PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158279/how-do-i-install-mysql-modules-within-php#160746)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: [How do I install MySQL modules within PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158279/how-do-i-install-mysql-modules-within-php#160746)

Answer (score 4):

Check out phpinfo to see if the mysql functions are compiled with your PHP

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Since in some versions of php, its not default with the install.

**Edit for the Update:**

You should have a full MySQL category in your phpinfo();

See this for example: https://secure18.easycgi.com/phpinfo.php (googled example)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the version of PHP you are using has not been compiled with MySQL support, or has not been enabled in the php.ini.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't got the MySQL PHP extensions installed! You shouldn't have to do any configuration other than installing the correct modules (and shouldn't be doing *anything* with ADODB).

PHP comes in 2 versions as well - a CGI version and an ISAPI module. You're best using the ISAPI version with ISS and adding all the trimmings...